# cy.visit crashes without meaningfull messages

Tags: cypress

I'm new to cypress and I want to create tests for a rather oldfashioned website which is unfortunatelly not available on the internet.

When I perform a simple call to the website cypress crashes:
cy.visit('http://10.0.0.6:8080/dmc')

The message I get within the chromium instance is: "Whoops, there is no test to run. Choose a test to run from the desktop application." 
Shortly before I get this message, I see some messages in red in the left chromium task-runner-pannel (sorry for not knowing the correct term). But the timespan is too short to read it.

So my questions are, any ideas why cypress is crashing? I know this may gonna be a tough one since the website is not accessable. 
Can I find these "red-messages" somewhere else? eg a logfile?

BR,
Richard

Comment: Can you please share the full test written in the test file.

Comment: Try putting a debugger in onBeforeLoad https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit.html#Syntax